# R Shiny - Triggering initial insertUI event programmatically in a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinymodules

The app below contains a `selectInput` (`input$month`) and a button, `Show Modal`, that launches a modal window when clicked. The modal contains a button, `Add UI`, that inserts some text, `Element x`, where `x` is the value of a counter that increases by 1 each time `Add UI` is clicked.

Screenshot of app on startup with the modal window opened:

[image]

The app is modularised so that UI associated with the modal is rendered by function `modUI` and the corresponding server logic is defined in function `modServer`. `modUI` is rerendered each time `input$month` changes to overwrite previously inserted text elements.

**I require the first block of text to be inserted programmatically, so that when the app loads *OR* the user changes `input$month`, `Element 1` is already rendered in the modal**:

[image]

To do this, I tried to get the insertUI observer to fire if `input$add_ui` greater than or equal to 0 - i.e. `observeEvent(if(req(input$add_ui) >= 0) TRUE else return(), { #insertUI expr })`. However, this doesn't work and I don't understand why. **Since observers are eagerly evaluated, shouldn't this observer fire after `input$add_ui` has finished initialising?**

The counter must also be reset to 0 each time `input$month` changes so that inserted text elements start at `Element 1`. To do this, I included the following observer in `modServer`:

```
observe({
    req(input$add_ui == 0) #checking that modUI has finished rerendering
    print(paste('month changed to:', month, 'resetting counter')); 
    counter(0)
  })
```

The `req(input$add_ui == 0)` checks if `modUI` has finished rerendering and the counter is only reset if the check is passed. **But I feel like this makes the `modServer` less self-contained and was wondering if there was a less roundabout way?**

**Lastly, I am relatively new to modules and was wondering if someone could explain why `counter()` is not reset automatically whenever `modServer` is called via  `observe(callModule(modServer, 'hi', month = input$month))`?** Why does its value persist if the module has its own environment?

I would be grateful for any help as I have been stuck on this for a while.

Code to reproduce the above:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

#MODULE UI ----
modUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("show_modal"), "Show modal"),
    bsModal(
      id = ns('modal'),
      trigger = ns('show_modal'),

      actionButton(ns("add_ui"), "Add UI"),
      tags$div(id = ns("placeholder1"))
    )
  )
}

#MODULE SERVER ----
modServer <- function(input, output, session, month) {

  ns <- session$ns

  counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  # Observer to insert UI element
  observeEvent(if(req(input$add_ui) >= 0) TRUE else return(), {

    counter(counter() + 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = paste0("#", ns("placeholder1")),
      ui = tags$div(paste('Element', counter()))
    )
  })

  # Reset counter() if month is changed
  observe({
    req(input$add_ui == 0)
    print(paste('month changed to:', month, 'resetting counter')); 
    counter(0)
  })

  # Print
  observe({ print(paste('input$add_ui:', input$add_ui, 'counter:', counter())) })

}

#MAIN UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    selectInput('month', 'Month', month.abb),
    uiOutput('modal_ui')
  )
)

#MAIN SERVER ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Call modUI if input$month is changed
  observe(callModule(modServer, 'hi', month = input$month))

  #Rerender modUI if input$month is changed
  output$modal_ui <- renderUI({
    input$month
    modUI('hi')
  })

  observe(print(input$month))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try to debug step by step and watch out the events. It seems when you are in new month, the event of previous month is still fired. At some lines I think you have to use `isolate()`. If you could, you have to prefer `ObserveEvent()`. Try to restart to write your source all without module and when I works restart to write  with module. Your source is confusing me even I tried it.

Comment: I tried   `counter<-reactiveValues()` and `counter[[month]]` but it has still the  issues that it seems when you are in new month, the event of previous month is still fired.

Comment: Please read this article [20/7/18, Using global input values inside of R Shiny modules,  by T Bradley](https://tbradley1013.github.io/2018/07/20/r-shiny-modules--using-global-inputs/) in particular the conclusion where it's written to use `reactive(input$myglobalinput)`, in your case `reactive(input$month)` for  input which are external at a module when you call a module, and inside the module to call the reactive parameter by `month()`. But try to read all the article :)